# Displaying a Table, Undefined Offset Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I want display tables in a blade view that should be like this:

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkC7j.png)

dynamically ...

When i add another User and attach a category it should display more tables.

I have 3 Tables in my Database: 
User, user_category and category

I defined the realtionship in my model files. 
A User can have many Categories.

I tried it with PHP variables and a @while blade expression.

```
@php
    $i=0;
@endphp

@foreach($users as $user)

    <!-- Display Table Header -->

    @while($Category[$i]->user_id == $user->id)

        <!-- Display Table Rows -->

        @php
            $i++;
        @endphp

    @endwhile


@endforeach
```

This gave me an error: Undefined Offset: 6.

I have currently 6 rows in my Table. I can display the content when i 'hardcode' the index, like this for example: $Category[5].
The Join Query in my Controller works. I sorted it ascendent by User ID

How do i solve this problem? I'm a beginner and currently learning laravel.
Yes, i googled my problem before. Sorry for my english

Comment: If you got 6 rows then the last index should be 5. Try to do something like `@foreach ($user->categories as $category) {{ $category->data1 }} .... @endforeach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, maybe this could help you. It's just an example but you get the point.

```
<ul>
@foreach ($users as $user)
   @foreach ($user->categories as $category)
    <li>{{ $category->property_1 }}</li>
    <li>{{ $category->property_2 }}</li>
    <li>{{ $category->property_3 }}</li>
   @endforeach 
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Please mark it as an answer if you find it correct